# React / Apollo: Displaying result of GraphQL query (useQuery hook)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am new to react/graphql/apollo however I have followed the guide on how to do a graphql query using Apollo on [www.apollographql.com](http://www.apollographql.com). However I don't seem to be able to show the result.

This is the code I am executing to do the query

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const GET_PRODUCTS = gql`
  query getProducts{
    products(first: 1) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
}
`;

const StartPage = () => {
  const { loading, error, returnData } = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS, {
    variables: {},
  });
 
  return (
    <p>Hello world, this should be the data: {returnData}</p>
  );
};
```

I only see "Hello world, this should be the data:" but the returnData is not printed?
Can't I just print the entire response?

When I reload the page I can clearly see in the networks tab that my query
does get executed and I get a correct response back

request

```
{"operationName":"getProducts","variables":{},"query":"query getProducts {\n  products(first: 1) {\n    edges {\n      node {\n        id\n        name\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}
```

response

```
{"data":{"products":{"edges":[{"node":{"id":"UHJvZHVjdDo3Mg==","name":"Apple Juice","__typename":"Product"},"__typename":"ProductCountableEdge"}],"__typename":"ProductCountableConnection"}}}
```

So does anyone have an idea why returnData is not printed / is empty?

Comment: can't you just copy/paste more code from example? ... `if(loading)...` is for some reason ... `data` can be renamed but other way ... I guess no earlier react loading data experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS, ...);` Note: `data` instead of `returnData`.

When you destructure objects, you need to be exact when it comes to the key. If you *need* the data to live in a variable called `returnData`, you could do something like this:

```js
const { loading, error, data: returnData } = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS, {
  variables: {},
});
```

Also be aware that in React you cannot just render objects inside curly braces, React expects a string or a number. For quick debugging you could add

```js
return (
  <p>Hello world, this should be the data: {JSON.stringify(returnData)}</p
);
```

Otherwise you should display data from deep inside the return object.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked! Only one follow up question, what if I just want to display the name of that first product given the query response I have provided isn't this how it is supposed to be printed : <p>Hello this should be the data {JSON.stringify(data)}, name: {data.products.edges[0].node.name}</p> however this does not work?

Comment: Ah nevermind I solved the follow up question. It turns out you really have to only print {data.products.edges[0].node.name} once you are sure the data is loaded, it could not contain those objects at first